# what does this() mean in Java

Tags: java, this

what does  `this()`  mean in Java?

It looks it is only valid when put

```
this();
```

in the class variable area.

Any one has idea about this?

Thanks.

Comment: I answered a similar question on a different post. Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867722/java-this-method-confusion

Answer (score 7):

It means you are calling the default constructor from another constructor. It has to be the first statement and you cannot use super() if you have. It is fairly rare to see it used.

Answer (score 6):

It's a call to the no-argument constructor, which you can call as the first statement in another constructor to avoid duplicating code.

```
public class Test {

        public Test() {
        }

        public Test(int i) {
          this();
          // Do something with i
        }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It means "call constructor which is without arguments". Example:

```
public class X {
    public X() {
        // Something.
    }
    public X(int a) {
        this();   // X() will be called.
        // Something other.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `this()` wil call the constructor of the class with no arguments.

You would use it like this:

```
public MyObj() { this.name = "Me!"; }
public MyObj(int age) { this(); this.age = age; }
```

Comment: oh god... don't do that!  public MyObj() {this("Me!");} public MyObj(String nm) { this(name, 0);} MyObj(String nm, int a) { name = nm; age = a; }

Comment: `function` isn't a Java keyword

Comment: @barrow: Mixing my languages again, thanks.

Comment: @Tufu: I was giving an example of how you would use it, not proper usage.

Answer (score 1):

It is a call to a constructor of the containing class.  See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 0):

See the example here: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/oop/constructors/constructor.html

You can call the constructor explicitly with this()

Answer (score 0):

a class calling its own default constructor.  It's more common to see it with arguments.