# Undefined type compile error when trying to define multiple constructors

Tags: java

main class->>>

```
public class scoreMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Football Score board

        Score scoreObject = new Score();
        Score scoreObject1 = new Score(1);
        Score scoreObject2 = new Score(1,2);
        Score scoreObject3 = new Score(1,2,3);

    }
}
```

and constructor class -->>>

```
public class Score {

    public void Score()
    {
        Score(0,0,0);
    }
    public void Score(int x)
    {
        Score(x,0,0);
    }
    public void Score(int x,int y)
    {
        Score(x,y,0);
    }
    public String Score(int x,int y,int z)
    {
       Score(x,y,z);
       return String.format("%d/%d%d",x,y,z);   
    }
}
```

but it shows error when creating objects ...
the constructor score(int) is undefined 
the constructor score(int int ) is undefined 
the constructor score(int int int ) is undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructors do not return anything. Not `String` nor `void` or anything else. You should just change the constructors as follows:

```
public class Score {

    public Score() {
        this(0,0,0);
    }

    public Score(int x) {
        this(x,0,0);
    }

    public Score(int x,int y){
        this(x,y,0);
    }

    public Score(int x,int y,int z) {
       Score(x,y,z); // Not sure what's this - you can't do a recursive constructor call. Doesn't make any sense
       return String.format("%d/%d%d",x,y,z); // Remove the return statment.
    }
}
```

**Also notice to not only not do a return on any value, but also you have a recursive call for the constructor in the last overloaded constructor. It doesn't make any sense and won't work.**

BTW - the correct way of overloading constructors is by calling `this()` inside the overloads and have only one implementation. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867769/2083523) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there are only methods, no constructors. Constructors have no return type.

Example:

```
public class Score {

  public Score()
  {
    this(0,0,0);
  }

  public Score(int x)
  {
    this(x,0,0);
  }

  public Score(int x,int y)
  {
    this(x,y,0);
  }

  public Score(int x,int y,int z)
  {
    //??
    //constructors cannot return anything!
    //return String.format("%d/%d%d",x,y,z);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to invoke other constructor of the same class, you should use keyword `this`, not class name.

So, first constructor would look like this

```
public void Score()
{
    this(0,0,0);
}
```

Also, what you have here is a method, not a constructor. Constructors don't have return types